# xcode - my app is referencing a xib file that is not there

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7

I was given a project half way down. The app is in a storyboard, when I run the app I goto a scene and I see elements in the app that I do not see in my scene:

[image]

when I look at the scenes header file, I can see my elements reference a .xib file:

[image]

When I look in XIB files, that file is not there:

[image]

But all the elements and buttons work in my app....this is very strange. I am able to click on the xib file and it opens, but I cant find anywhere else and if I change something in the xib file, then it does not change in my app.

Answer (score 0):

The XIB probably exists on the filesystem, but may not have been added to the Xcode project or target, or more likely, was removed from the project or target at some point - try looking for it in the filesystem and adding it to Xcode and see if that fixes the problem, or if you can find it in Xcode, adding it to your build target - if it had been in the target and isn't, unless you do a clean build, the compiled NIB will remain so app would continue working but changes would not propagate into the app since the XIB isn't being compiled/packaged.